# Rails - expire_after on session_store does not allow session to be changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, session, cookies

My site is a single page rails app that interacts with a rails api. I recently added an api endpoint that allows a user to log out via ajax.

```
class Api::SessionsController < Api::ApplicationController
  ...      

  # DELETE /api/sessions/destroy
  def destroy
    session.delete(:user_id)
    render json: { success: true }
  end

  ...
end
```

This endpoint was working fine until I altered my session store to keep the session around when a user quits their browser.

`config/initializers/session_store.rb` diff:

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store,
-  key: session_key, domain: TOP_LEVEL_DOMAIN
+  key: session_key, domain: TOP_LEVEL_DOMAIN, expire_after: 1.month
```

Now, after hitting my `sessions#destroy` endpoint via ajax, reloading the page logs the user back in, and still has the user_id in the session.

My guess is that the browser's cookie is not being overwritten by the `DELETE` ajax request (like it was before I added the expire_after parameter), but this is very tough to verify because the stored cookie is encrypted.

Does anyone have any solution ideas or debugging paths?

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

When you set `:expire_after` to set the expiration of the cookie, it causes the cookie to persist to the given date even when the browser is closed. This means that when you change something in the session of Rails, you have to **update the cookie**. The simplest to way to achieve that is recreating the cookie.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are suggesting I do.. Are you saying I should update the cooking on the client side after the response? Shouldn't default rails handle updating the cookie when the session has changed?

Comment: Exactly. This article explains it better http://augustl.com/blog/2010/dynamic_session_expiration_time_in_rails_3/